# Android retrofit show only some of the results

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, filter

I am getting data from json via retrofit. The server gives me all data, but I want to show in recyclerview only some of them (which are marked in users database locally on their device).

In recycleradapter I tried it like this:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.MyviewHolder holder, int position) {

        final DatabaseHelper myDb;
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        boolean is_visited = myDb.CheckDB(movieList.get(position).getAdresar());

        boolean is_filter = filterData (is_visited, className);

        if(is_filter) {

            holder.tvTitle.setText(movieList.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.tvPerex.setText(movieList.get(position).getPerex());

        }
    }

    private boolean filterData (boolean is_visited, String className) {
        if (className.equals("Visited")) {
            return is_visited;
        }
        else
        {return true;}
    }
```

So in this case, if the database value is true, filterData returns true and only in that case I want to show the item.

However it is showing the required results, but for the rest (with filterData false) it is still showing an empty placeholder.

So how can I show only required data? And also if there is no data to show, I wanna e.g.change the background image or show some message (I can't do this in onResponse, as there are always results from the server, I just don't want to show some of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the placeholder by setVisibility(View.GONE)
in your code,

```
 boolean is_filter = filterData (is_visited, className);
   if(is_filter) {
        holder.tvTitle.setText(movieList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tvPerex.setText(movieList.get(position).getPerex());

    }
 else{
      holder.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE)
      holder.tvPerex.setVisibility(View.GONE)
      //do the code for changing background image or set text if there is no data
      }
```

Comment: well, seems an easy solution for my case. I also found other solution, to create a new list inside onResponse and that list will be already filtered, but your solution is the simplest for my code structure. Thanks!